# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute height in BST pythons height

Tags: python, data-structures, tree, height, binary-search-tree

This is my code for creating a BST in python everything is working fine but when i accesses height function it gives error like "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute height"i am new to creating datastructures in python any help will be appriciated

```
 class Node:
        def __init__(self, data):
            self.left = None
            self.right = None
            self.data = data
        def insert(self, data):
            if self.data:
                if data < self.data:
                    if self.left is None:
                        self.left = Node(data)
                    else:
                        self.left.insert(data)
                elif data > self.data:
                    if self.right is None:
                        self.right = Node(data)
                    else:
                        self.right.insert(data)
            else:
                self.data = data

        def print_tree(self):

            if self.left:
                self.left.print_tree()
            print (self.data)
            if self.right:
                self.right.print_tree()

        def height(self):
            if self.data is None:
                return 0
            else:
                return 1 + max(self.left.height(),self.right.height())

    root = Node(8)
    root.insert(3)
    root.insert(10)
    root.insert(1)
    root.insert(6)
    root.insert(4)
    root.insert(7)
    root.insert(14)
    root.insert(13)
    root.print_tree()
    root.height()
```

Comment: For leaf nodes, `self.data` is not None , but `self.left` and `self.right` would be None , hence the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For leaf nodes in your tree, `self.data` would be set to the value of the leaf node , but `self.left` and `self.right` would be `None`. But even before that, there can be nodes where either left or right child is `None` and since we try that node and get its height we get the `AttributeError` on `NoneType` .

In the code for `height` -

```
def height(self):
    if self.data is None:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1 + max(self.left.height(),self.right.height())
```

when the recursion reaches a node, where either `left` or `right` node is None, the above code would fail because it would try to access `self.left.height()` or `self.right.height()` , and one of them is None.

We can add a simple check to see if either `self.left` or `self.right` is `None` , and based on that get the height from the it.

Answer (score 0):

If you get an error like that it means you try to use a field of a `None`. Because your tree is finite you have a leaf that doesn't have any data. I see you have a place in the code where `self.data` field is assigned to a value but `self.left` and `self.right` don't. At the same time, you get values of the fields in `height` method, you check only `self.data`. That doesn't make sense for me.

Also, I suggest trying `pdb` or another debugging tool.